# Connecting Ubuntu to Algo VPN

Tags: network-manager

Does anyone have experience with connecting to an Algo VPN on a Ubuntu 16.04 client (running Gnome)?

Would really love to know how to best do this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a little but now i get some problem setting the server, seeing [this](https://github.com/trailofbits/algo/issues/263) using strongswan or wireguard you should.
And this is what says https://github.com/trailofbits/algo/blob/master/docs/client-linux.md :
(Gnome) Network Manager configuration 
 
In this example we'll assume the IP of our Algo VPN server is 1.2.3.4 and the user we created is user-name.

```
Go to Settings > Network
Add a new Network (+ bottom left of the window)
Select IPsec/IKEv2 (strongswan)
Fill out the options:
    Name: your choice, e.g.: ikev2-1.2.3.4
    Gateway:
        Address: IP of the Algo VPN server, e.g: 1.2.3.4
        Certificate: cacert.pem found at /path/to/algo/configs/1.2.3.4/cacert.pem
    Client:
        Authentication: Certificate/Private key
        Certificate: user-name.crt found at /path/to/algo/configs/1.2.3.4/pki/certs/user-name.crt
        Private key: user-name.key found at /path/to/algo/configs/1.2.3.4/pki/private/user-name.key
    Options:
        Check Request an inner IP address, connection will fail without this option
        Optionally check Enforce UDP encapsulation
        Optionally check Use IP compression
        For the later 2 options, hover to option in the settings to see a description
    Cipher proposal:
        Check Enable custom proposals
        IKE: aes256gcm16-prfsha512-ecp384,aes256-sha2_512-prfsha512-ecp384,aes256-sha2_384-prfsha384-ecp384
        ESP: aes256gcm16-ecp384,aes256-sha2_512-prfsha512-ecp384
Apply and turn the connection on, you should now be connected
```